# How to know my classes in Latent Dirichlet Allocation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda, unsupervised-learning

I'm using sklearn and this is my code so far:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation
lda_model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=5, learning_method='online', max_iter=2

X_topics = lda_model.fit_transform(X)
topic_word = lda_model.components_ 

#vectorizer is from countVectorizer
y=vectorizerN.transform(["some text here"])

lda_model.transform(y)

array([[0.05000144, 0.05000128, 0.05000162, 0.05000113, 0.79999453]])
```

Now, it only show me those 5 probabilities, but how can I know what are my classes?

Comment: Your code is incomplete (what is `vectorizerN`, `X` , `Y` ?) but maybe you just want to use `predict(Y)`  instead of `transform(Y)`?

Comment: @ilja lda doesn't have predict function, i edited the post

Comment: oh, yes my fault... I thought It was LDA = Linear Discriminant Analysis (`from sklearn.lda import LDA` ... but maybe that is what you want instead of Latent Dirichlet Allocation? Because Latent Dirichlet Allocation **is** just a transformation. If you want classes (prediction?) use a classifier, e.g. Linear Discriminant Analysis.

Comment: @ilja you're again completely mistaken, this is for topic modeling, it has nothing to do with linear discriminant analysis

Comment: @GaMeRGaMeR what do you mean know your classes ? knowing the 5 topics of your LDA model ?

Comment: @IsmailChafai yes, so when I pass the text, I can know what topic it's about. I have 5 topics, and I don't know how to map them to the output probabilities it's giving me

Comment: Ok, yes you can get top words from each of the 5 topics which will indeed let you understand your predictions. Did you use tfidf to vectorize your text data ?

Comment: @IsmailChafai yes, i used countvectorizer. So you're saying I first get the top words, and then I see to what class the top words are from, and then I label the words right?